# google maps, client libraries node js, distance matrix request js

Tags: node.js, google-maps, google-distancematrix-api, client-library

I am trying to implement a google maps distance matrix api request using, node JS google Client library. specifically

```
@googlemaps/google-maps-services-js
```

The problem am facing, I can only finds source code example for elevation in the documentation.

```
const client = new Client({});

client
  .elevation({
    params: {
      locations: [{ lat: 45, lng: -110 }],
      key: "asdf",
    },
    timeout: 1000, // milliseconds
  })
  .then((r) => {
    console.log(r.data.results[0].elevation);
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log(e.response.data.error_message);
  });
```

I need source code example for Distance Matrix so I can implement point to point distance calculation within node JS, using the client library.

```
const client = new Client({});

client
  .distanceMatrixrequest()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
client
      .distancematrix({
        params: {
          key: '<YOUR_KEY>',
          origins: ['Greenwich, England'],
          destinations: ['Stockholm, Sweden'],
          travelMode: 'DRIVING',
          // Feel free to set more params
        },

        timeout: 1000, // milliseconds
      })
      .then((r) => {
        console.log(r.data.rows[0]?.elements);
        res.json(r.data);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e.response.data.status);
      });
```

Response comes in this format:

```
[
  {
    distance: { text: '1,880 km', value: 1880123 },
    duration: { text: '20 hours 59 mins', value: 75548 },
    status: 'OK'
  }
]
```